# Woocommerce custom sign up form template

Tags: validation, woocommerce, registration

I have created custom template for Woocommerce registration page. By creating new template in my child theme.

Below is the code I am using. the issue here is it does not validate the form. It is not displaying any error messages.

Do I need to write all the validation by myself? Woocommerce validation will not work here?

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: [Sign Up]
 */
 ?>

<?php if(is_user_logged_in()){
  wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')));
} ?>
<?php get_header();?>
 
        
<div class="page-layout page-padding">
    <div class="container-small login-padding">
    
    <div class="sign-up-form-title">
           <h2 style="text-align: center;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' );  ?></h2>
            <p>Create New Account</p>
        </div>    
      
        
<form method="post" class="sign-up-form-container" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >
<div class="login-information1">
        
    <div class="col-1-personal-information"> 
    
        
          <h2>Personal Information </h2>
  
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>
    <p class="">
    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="sign-up-form-fields" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    </p>
        

        <?php endif; ?>

        
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-login-information">
        <h2>Sign-in Information  </h2>
        <p class="">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp; <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class= "sign-up-form-fields" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
        </p>
        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="">
                <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp; <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="sign-up-form-fields" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['password'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['password'] ) ) : ''; ?>"/>
            </p>

        <?php else : ?>

            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?> -->

        
    </div>
        
        
</div>
        
        <p class="sign-up-footer">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="form-button1" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Creat an Account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        </p>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
        <p class="sign-up-footer-text">Already have an account? Go to &nbsp <a href="/my-account/">Login</a></p>
    </form>
    
    
    </div>
</div>

    

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have added additional field by adding below code in funtion.php file

```
/ 1. ADD FIELDS
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration' );
  
function bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration() {
    ?>
  
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
  
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_company"><?php _e( 'Company name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_company" id="reg_billing_company" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_company'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_company'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    

    <div class="clear"></div>
  
    <?php
}
  
///////////////////////////////
// 2. VALIDATE FIELDS
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'bbloomer_validate_name_fields', 10, 3 );
  
function bbloomer_validate_name_fields( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    return $errors;
}
  
///////////////////////////////
// 3. SAVE FIELDS
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'bbloomer_save_name_fields' );
  
function bbloomer_save_name_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_company'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_company', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_company'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'company_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_company']) );
    }
   
}
```

This is adding the fields to the form saving it in the account.
But the issue here validation is not working. It even does not work for the the default username and password.

If the user is already registered then also it does not show validation.

[image]